# How does JUnit mask checked exceptions?

Tags: junit5

JUnit 5 masks checked exceptions with this code:

```java
public static RuntimeException throwAsUncheckedException(Throwable t) {
    Preconditions.notNull(t, "Throwable must not be null");
    ExceptionUtils.throwAs(t);

    // Appeasing the compiler: the following line will never be executed.
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Throwable> void throwAs(Throwable t) throws T {
    throw (T) t;
}
```

In the call to throwAs, how does Java decide on the value of the type variable T?

More importantly, how does this code mask a checked exception?

Comment: In which class did you find this source code? Why is the return type `RuntimeException`. Setting the return type to `void` will not need to 'appease the compiler'. I wonder why there is no need to `try-catch` around the call of `throwAs`

Comment: The code is from org.junit.platform.commons.util.ExceptionUtils. According to the source code, "the return type is merely present to allow this method [throwAsUncheckedException] to be supplied as the operand in a throw statement."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `T` is inferred to be `RuntimeException`. I'm inferring that from making the following change to the code of `throwAsUncheckedException`:

```
var o = ExceptionUtils.throwAs(t);
```

... and changing the declaration of `throwAs` to:

```
private static <T extends Throwable> T throwAs(Throwable t) throws T
```

(Note that I'm using `var` from Java 10 to let the compiler infer the type without any further information being provided.)

After compiling and then using `javap -c` you can see that there's a `checkcast` to `RuntimeException`:

```
invokestatic  #2  // Method throwAs:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/Throwable;
checkcast     #3  // class java/lang/RuntimeException
astore_1
```

That makes it fine for `throwAs` not to declare that it throws anything else - it's only calling a method that declares that it throws `T`, so `RuntimeException` in this case.

Further somewhat specious evidence for this is in [JLS section 18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html), which includes this line:

> Otherwise, if the bound set contains throws αi, and each proper upper bound of αi is a supertype of `RuntimeException`, then Ti = `RuntimeException`.

No other concrete exception types, or `Throwable`, are mentioned in that section. Unfortunately I find section 18 pretty much impenetrable, so this is really more of a "yes, that vaguely supports my theory" rather than good evidence.

In this particular case, I believe it would actually be fine (and simpler in terms of understanding) for the `throwAsUncheckedException` method to just specify the type argument explicitly:

```
ExceptionUtils.<RuntimeException>throwAs(t);
```

So that's how the *compiler* is molified. It *thinks* that only `RuntimeException` will be thrown. The *actual* value thrown is whatever's passed in though. The cast to `T` is ignored for all the normal type erasure reasons... if you change the code to *actually* cast to `RuntimeException`, it will fail for any checked exception. That's why it needs to be a generic method: to include a cast that satisfies the compiler without really casting at execution time.

The JVM allows this because as far as I'm aware, checked exceptions are purely a compiler aspect, and there's no validation for them in the JVM itself. It just knows about throwing exceptions.